# Google Apps Script - How to Move File From Active Folder to Most Recent Months Folder In Google Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Each month, I move files from one active folder (Prep) to 5 different folders (Toyota,Honda,Mercedes,General Motors,Ford) in the Google Shared Drive. Each month, a new subfolder for the month (ex: January/February/March/August) is added into each of the 5 folders that were mentioned above. The files from the active folder (Prep) would then be moved to the 5 folders depending on the name of the file. For example: Next month, the file 'Toyota Claims' will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder, while the 'Ford Complaints' file will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder.

Each month, the files in the active folder (Prep) will have the same names. The destination folders will also have the same names. The only thing that will be different is that a new month subfolder will be created and the files in the active folder will be moved to the new months subfolder in each Car Manufacturer folder. Since the car manufacturer folders don't change, their folder Ids will always be the same.

Right now, the code (see below) I have only allows me to move the file if I manually find the parent folder id, destination folder id, and file id and input them manually into the macro.

```
function moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(parentFolderId, destinationFolderID, fileId ) {
  const data = Drive.Files.update({}, fileId, null, {
    addParents: destinationFolderID, 
    removeParents: parentFolderId,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: 'title,embedLink',
  });
  console.log('File Moved', data.title, data.embedLink);
}

moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives("1FhaTIWcQZ-ykXCXnGHgSl59334RYAngr","1setPITRSnsK7yTHs-sL3UepcFNPTaDcv", "1R9gLWEpGjnkHLTgmCISL5QNQJbVU-9QZwNXu44HKCLI")
moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives("1FhaTIWcQZ-ykXCXnGHgSl59334RYAngr","1badWtc7OG4vZ2J-kYvljmB-gH97WKE-Z", "1SiAyMZiPENQjfJSYHREi9b0pq_VBWAu_")
```

The active folder Id will always be the same. Since the car manufacturer folders don't change, their folder Ids will also always be the same. How can I add conditions to this code that will allow me to select the most recent months folder. Is there a way to use several if statements to find the most recent month present and then save the files in there? Also, how can I modify this code to hardcode the various files names into the script rather than use the file ID to move the file. The file names will be unique in the active folder.

Edited: Here is an image to better show what I'm trying to do: There's files in an active (parent) folder that I want to move to other folders based on the name of the file.[image]

Comment: About `For example: Next month, the file 'Toyota Claims' will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder, while the 'Ford Complaints' file will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder.`, in your goal, you want to move all folders under the folder of "Prep" to the specific folder under the "Toyota" folder. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: And, in your situation, "Prep" folder has no subfolders while 5 files are existing. And, the 5 folders of "Toyota,Honda,Mercedes,General Motors,Ford" have several subfolders with the folder name of each month. And, all filenames and folders are constant. Is my understanding of your situation correct? And, your goal is that you want to move the files in "Prep" folder to each month's folder of 5 folders. Is my understanding of your goal correct?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I really appreciate you looking into this! To answer your questions. For the 1st question:  My goal is to move the files that have Toyota in the file name in the "Prep" folder to the "August" (newest month) folder inside the "Toyota" folder.

Comment: For the 2nd question: Yes, the "Prep" folder has no subfolders. It just has Google Sheets files within it. Yes, the 5 car manufacturer folders have subfolders inside that have the name of each month. Yes, all filenames and folders are constant. Yup, my goal is to move the files in "Prep" folder to each month's folder of the 5 car manufacturer folders. The only thing is, the files must have the same car manufacturer name as the folder it will be placed into. So a "Toyota Claims" file has to go only into the 'Toyota' folder. It can't go into the 'Ford' folder.

Comment: I added an image to my question for reference. Thanks again @Tanaike for looking into this!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `For example: Next month, the file 'Toyota Claims' will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder, while the 'Ford Complaints' file will be moved to the August subfolder in the Toyota folder.`, in this case, you want to move both the files of "Toyota Claims" and "Ford Complaints" to "August" folder in "Toyota"? Or, you want to move "Ford Complaints" file to "August" folder in "Ford" folder?

Comment: And, I would like to confirm your current situation. In your current situation, when you use your function of `moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives`, the files in the shared Drive can be moved without any errors? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, sorry, that was a typo on my part. Yes, the "Toyota Claims" file should go to the "August" folder in "Toyota" and the "Ford Complaints" file should go to "August" folder in the "Ford Folder".

Comment: Yes, the moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives function has worked for me. I was able to successfully move files between two folders in the Google Shared drive

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- There are folders of "Prep" and "Toyota,Honda,Mercedes,General Motors,Ford" in the shared Drive.

  - These folder names and IDs are constant.
- There are several files like "Toyota Claims", "Ford Complaints" in "Prep" folder.
- For example, when this month is July, you want to move the file of "Toyota Claims" to "August" folder in "Toyota" folder. And also, you want to move the file of "Ford Complaints" to "August" folder in "Ford" folder.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- From your reply of `Yes, the moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives function has worked for me. I was able to successfully move files between two folders in the Google Shared drive`, your showing script of `moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives` can be used for moving the files in the shared Drive without any errors.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, your function of `moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives` is used. Before you use this script, please set the variables of `srcFolderId` (folder ID of "Prep" folder) and `folders` (folder IDs of "Toyota,Honda,Mercedes,General Motors,Ford" folders). And, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
function moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(parentFolderId, destinationFolderID, fileId) {
  const data = Drive.Files.update({}, fileId, null, {
    addParents: destinationFolderID,
    removeParents: parentFolderId,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: 'title,embedLink',
  });
  console.log('File Moved', data.title, data.embedLink);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  // Please set the folder IDs of 6 folders you want to use.
  const srcFolderId = "###"; // Please set folder ID of "Prep" folder.
  const folders = {
    "Toyota": "###", // Please set folder ID of "Toyota" folder.
    "Honda": "###", // Please set folder ID of "Honda" folder.
    "Mercedes": "###", // Please set folder ID of "Mercedes" folder.
    "General Motors": "###", // Please set folder ID of "General Motors" folder.
    "Ford": "###", // Please set folder ID of "Ford" folder.
  };

  // Retrieve next month as a text.
  const date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  const nextMonth = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM");

  // Retrieve files in "Prep" folder.
  const params = { corpora: "allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, fields: "items(title,id)" };
  const keys = Object.keys(folders).map(e => e.toLowerCase());
  const fileObj = Drive.Files.list({ q: `'${srcFolderId}' in parents and mimeType != '${MimeType.FOLDER}' and trashed=false`, ...params }).items.reduce((o, { title, id }) => {
    const temp = keys.find(e => title.toLowerCase().includes(e));
    if (temp) o[temp] = o[temp] ? [...o[temp], id] : [id];
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Move files from the source folder to the destination folders.
  Object.entries(folders).forEach(([name, id]) => {
    const dstFolder = Drive.Files.list({ q: `'${id}' in parents and mimeType = '${MimeType.FOLDER}' and trashed=false`, ...params }).items.find(({ title }) => title == nextMonth);
    const srcFiles = fileObj[name.toLowerCase()];
    if (dstFolder && srcFiles && srcFiles.length > 0) {
      srcFiles.forEach(srcFileId => moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(srcFolderId, dstFolder.id, srcFileId));
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the files are retrieved from "Prep" folder, and by searching the destination folder of the month, those files are moved.

#### Note:

- In this case, if you cannot move the files by permission, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- If an error occurs when the files are moved in your script of `moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives`, please modify it as follows, and test it again.

  ```
    function moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives(parentFolderId, destinationFolderID, fileId) {
      Drive.Files.copy({parents: [{id: destinationFolderID}], title: DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName()}, fileId, {supportsTeamDrives: true});
      Drive.Files.remove(fileId, {supportsAllDrives: true});
      console.log('File Moved', fileId);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike! I really appreciate you looking into this. I ran the code and it semi-worked. I tried this with just 4 files. 2 for Ford and 2 for Toyota. The 4 files were named "Ford Claims", "Ford Complaints", "Toyota Claims", "Toyota Complaints". The "Ford Claims" and "Toyota Claims" files made it into the "August" subfolder in "Ford" and "Toyota" folders respectively. However, the "Toyota Complaints" and "Ford Complaints" files remained in the "Prep" folder. Do you have an idea why those 2 files didn't move?

Comment: I also tried the code with the moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives function that you'd updated and it also did that. Except in your version, the files that were in "Prep" folder was surprisingly replaced with "Copy of Ford Complaints", "Copy of Toyota Complaints", "Copy of Ford Claims", and "Copy of Toyota Complaints" files.

Comment: @Jackson Smith Thank you for replying. From your question, I thought that your files are 5 files including `Toyota,Honda,Mercedes,General Motors,Ford`. So, in my proposed script, for example, the file of filename includes "Toyota" is only one in "Prep" folder. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Now, I updated my sample script for using multiple files of filename including "Toyota". Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Jackson Smith About `I also tried the code with the moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives function that you'd updated and it also did that. Except in your version, the files that were in "Prep" folder were surprisingly replaced with "Copy of Ford Complaints", "Copy of Toyota Complaints", "Copy of Ford Claims", and "Copy of Toyota Complaints" files.`, from `Yes, the moveFilesBetweenSharedDrives function has worked for me. I was able to successfully move files between two folders in the Google Shared`, I think that this might not be required to be used. But, I removed this bug.

Comment: Also @Tanaike, one additional question that I just thought of as I tried this code. Will the code still work if the monthly subfolder has a year in it? So the "August" folder would be "August 2022" and next year this time in July, there will be a folder named "August 2023"? I apologize for adding this complexity. I just thought about it now

Comment: @Jackson Smith Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, in the current script, the folder name of `August 2022` cannot be used. In this case, when `"MMMM"` is modified to `"MMMM yyyy"`, the folder name of `August 2022` is searched. But, if this was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246725/discussion-between-jackson-smith-and-tanaike).

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, I wasn't sure how the posting in chat works, so just incase, I'm posting my comment here as well: "The absolute last question I have is, would this code still work if there's the month folder is within another folder that is within the ex:Toyota folder? Right now, the code works for Toyota Folder --> August SubFolder. Is it possible to update the code to get it to work for Toyota Folder --> Monthly Reporting SubFolder --> August SubFolder. It would really be a major help for me"

Comment: @Jackson Smith About your 3rd question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. So can you post it as a new question? By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I'll post it as a new question, thank you Tanaike!